# Creating Login System with Java only no databases and Jpanel/Jswing

Tags: java, authentication, system

So basically this is homework/classwork and we are asked to refrain from usin J.Frame and databases and all that stuff. So how do I create a login system that has 4 usernames and that for each user they have their own first name and last name? As you can see below currently it only asks for password and not username, password and the user's first and last name. Also I found the code for that but I'm not sure how to add a new username and the other two variables and the code was created by someone on stackoverflow so I'm not sure if I can post it here or not.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here
    login("James");
    String[][] data = generateData();        
    while(true){
        System.out.println("\n1 for printing");
        System.out.println("2 for charges");
        System.out.println("3 for payment");
    System.out.println("4 for adding a new account");
        System.out.println("0 to exit");
        System.out.print("What you want to do: ");
        int input = 0;
        try{
            input = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Wrong input, must enter an integer!");
            continue;
        }
        if (input == 0){
            printToFile(data);
            break;
        } else{
            switch(input){
                case 1: printing(data);
                        break;
                case 2: charges(data);
                        break;
                case 3: payment(data);  
                        break;
        case 4: add(data);
            data = generateData(); 
            break;
                default: System.out.println("Wrong input, must enter 0-4!");
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void add(String[][] x) throws IOException{
System.out.print("Enter your student ID: ");
String a = s.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter your First Name: ");
String b = s.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter your Last Name ");
String c = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your Contact Number: ");
String d = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your Email Address: ");
String e = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your Car Plate Number: ");
String f = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Today's Date: ");
String g = s.nextLine();
    int counter = x.length;
    File data = new File("data.txt");
PrintWriter y = new PrintWriter(data);
    y.println(counter+1);
for(int i=0; i<counter; i++){
        y.println();
        y.println(x[i][0]);
        y.println(x[i][1]);
        y.println(x[i][2]);
        y.println(x[i][3]);
        y.println(x[i][4]);
        y.println(x[i][5]);
        y.println(x[i][6]);
}
y.println();
    y.println(a);
    y.println(b);
    y.println(c);
    y.println(d);
    y.println(e);
    y.println(f);
    y.println(g);
    y.close();      
}
public static void printToFile(String[][] x) throws IOException{
    int counter = x.length;
    File data = new File("data.txt");
PrintWriter y = new PrintWriter(data);
    y.println(counter);
for(int i=0; i<counter; i++){
        y.println();
        y.println(x[i][0]);
        y.println(x[i][1]);
        y.println(x[i][2]);
        y.println(x[i][3]);
        y.println(x[i][4]);
        y.println(x[i][5]);
        y.println(x[i][6]);
}
    y.close();
}
public static void login(String password){
    System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
    String input = s.nextLine();
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        if( !(input.equals(password)) ){
            System.out.println("Wrong password!");
            if(i==1){
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("Last chance!");                
            System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
            input = s.nextLine();
            i++;
        } else{
            break;
        }
    }
}
public static String[][] generateData() throws IOException{
    File x = new File("data.txt");
Scanner y = new Scanner(x);
    int counter = Integer.parseInt(y.nextLine());
    String[][] data = new String[counter][7];
    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++){
        y.nextLine();
        data[i][0] = y.nextLine();
        data[i][1] = y.nextLine();
        data[i][2] = y.nextLine();
        data[i][3] = y.nextLine();
        data[i][4] = y.nextLine();
        data[i][5] = y.nextLine();
        data[i][6] = y.nextLine();
}
    y.close();
    return data;
}
public static void printing(String[][] data){
    int length1 = data.length;
    int length2 = data[0].length;
    for(int i=0; i<length1; i++){
        System.out.println(" ID "+Integer.parseInt(data[i][0])+", First Name: "+data[i][1]+", Last Name: "+data[i][2]+", Contact Number: "+data[i][3]+", Email Address: "+data[i][4]+", Car Number: "+data[i][5]+", Date Registered: "+data[i][6]);
    }
}
public static void charges(String[][] data){
    int length1 = data.length;
    for(int i=0; i<length1; i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+" for "+data[i][0]);
    }
    System.out.print("Who you want to charge: ");
    int input = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    System.out.print("How much you want to charge "+data[input-1][0]+": ");
    data[input-1][2] = ""+(Double.parseDouble(data[input-1][2]) + Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine()));
} 
public static void payment(String[][] data){
    int length1 = data.length;
    for(int i=0; i<length1; i++){
        System.out.println(" (ID "+Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]));
    }
    System.out.print("Who want to pay: ");
    int input = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    System.out.print("How much "+data[input-1][0]+" want to pay: ");
    data[input-1][2] = ""+(Double.parseDouble(data[input-1][2]) - Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine()));
}
```

}

Comment: Are you allowed to store the user name/passwords, maybe in a text file?

Comment: Did you know variable names are allowed to be more than one letter long?

Comment: @immibis what do you mean?

Comment: Okay, then which part are you stuck on?  Loading the file? Comparing the values? Prompting the user?

Comment: I don't know where to start, I didn't even know you can use txt file to write usernames on :\ @MadProgrammer ok I'm currently searching codes regarding for this..

Comment: Start with this idea, you need a user with `firstName`, `lastName` and `password` information, you would probably want a `User` class to hold this information.  You could also provide a `matches` method which takes the login information and asks this class if it matches the contained details...This means you can get the check up and running reasonably fast (with dummy data) and then add the I/O stuff later...